# Create a hidden table column

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I am using Django and Django tables2.
I read the documentation but couldn't find an answer to this question.
For some reason (database query) I need to store the primary keys of the database table in a column in the table which is not displayed at the webpage.

Do I have to explicitly check for each column and make it invisible or is there something better available in the django tables 2 api.

Comment: Do want to expand a little more on what problem you are trying to solve? What you mean by "database query") I have not been working that much with HTML, but it seems to me that there is a better way than a hidden column.

Comment: Oh okay,
The primary key of my table should not be shown to the user ('so as to look user friendly') I am trying to hide it but it is necessary I give that info because on updating the table I want the primary key to go to my handling script so that I can query my database for that key.

Comment: Why not just use the exclude Meta option in your ModelTable ?

Comment: How do I do it for individual columns using meta?

Answer (score 2):

The column Id (primary key) is *created* by default with Django and *shown* by default with django tables2. So no need to create it. If you want to go the simple way to hide it, you can do that in the tempates css. I added this to my template which will make sure that it is not shown.

```
<style type="text/css">                                                                          
      td.id, th.id {                                                                                                                                                                                   
        display:none;                                                                                                                                                                                            
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                          
</style>
```

I'm still not quite sure if I have understood you. But if this is what you are trying to do, this will work.

Comment: I do not see that column id my table and I am using django tables2.
I made a workaround of checking that if the forloop.counter variable was 1 I created a hidden field else a normal field for both thead nd tbody.
I do not understand what you are trying to achieve with this css. Do I apply it to only a specific column. IF yes then how without using my technique which is rather ugly

Comment: It is strange if you don't see it. Look at it's docs http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ the model have no id column still it shows up in the screenshot: http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_images/tutorial.png

Comment: Well it is showing an 'id' field at forloop.counter=0 now that I checked and its already hidden cause I never saw it in my table.
I used my own hidden field now very similar to what it was doing.
+1 for giving the info.